# How can I manage different screens on a Windows Phone 7 application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

For example, I want a button to take me to a settings page, and then back to the main screen. Just as an example for me to understand the workflow. Any guidance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the `NavigationService` to navigate to the new page, where the `Uri` has a path relative to the project's base directory.

```
private void OptionsMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Navigate to the new page
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/OptionsView.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

The back button on the phone will take the user back to the previous page automatically, or you could code you own return button using the `NavigationService` again.

Comment: Is this the standard way of doing it?

Comment: This is the standard method as far as I know -- or should I say that it's the only method I've seen used in the training materials I have viewed.

Answer (score 1):

Dr. Herbie's method works great.

Another option is to implement INavigate on your PhoneApplicationPage. Then use a HyperlinkButton. If you have a lot of buttons and don't want to write a bunch of click handlers, this can be more convenient.

Your implementation of INavigate.Navigate just uses the page's NavigationService like this:

```
    public bool Navigate(Uri source)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(source);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Now that's just devious! I'll most certainly share this tip.

Answer (score 1):

You must take care of certification requirements! Look at this tutorial: http://www.yourwindowsphone7.com/tutorials/navigation-in-windows-phone-7-apps.html